# How to check if only one of the argparse parameters exists

Tags: python, argparse

As in the code, there are two parser.add_argument --date and --type. If --type exists, I want to use another function. How can I check the existence of --type?
I tried this but it failed

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument('--date', default=str(startDate))
 parser.add_argument('--type', required=False)
 args = parser.parse_args()
 if len(args.type) > 0:
    dataFrame = spDataFrame[nospDataFrame['Type'] == args.type].reset_index(drop=True)
 else:
    campDataframe = sp_camp_mapping(startDate, endDate, keyword, driver, filePath)
    sp_mapping(campDataframe, driver, startDate)
```

`ERROR:None type has no len`

Comment: Include a `print(args)` in your debugging to see exactly what the `parser` has done.  It will save you confusion like this.  With simple definitions like this the argument will be the default (e.g. `None`) or a string.  You have to specify a `nargs` (like '+') to get a list (which as a `len`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `--type` parameter is not passed then the key `type` in args will have a value of `None` and:

```
    len(None)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
        exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What you can do is check the value of `args.type` directly:

```
import argparse

startDate = '20210209'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--date', default=str(startDate))
parser.add_argument('--type', required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.type:
    print("Type parameter was passed: {}".format(args.type))
else:
    print("Type parameter wasn't passed: {}".format(args.type))
```

Note: `if args.type` is equivalente to say `if args.type is not None:`